# How do I disable comments on a page?

Tags: comments

I want to disable comments on my pages. That means there should be no comment form, no message asking to log in in order to post comments, nothing.

Under `Settings > Discussion` is the option "Allow people to post comments on new articles." That implies that disabling comments on pages is possible, assuming that "article" means "post or page."

Unfortunately, a comment form still appears despite my unchecking this box. I thought that the option might be overridden on the page itself, but there are no relevant options on the page edit screen.

I really don't want to hack my theme when the facility to disable comments clearly exists already. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This question is better asked at the [official WordPress support forums](http://wordpress.org/support). For a given page, ensure "Discussion" is enabled in "Screen Options", and then you can configure per-page comment settings.

Comment: I'm flagging this as a dup because my apparently poor reading skills didn't identify an already-existing answer to this question. Feel free to pile the flags on...